# DBT is unable to find stored manifest.json file only while running on Github action runner

Tags: github-actions, dbt

We have a repository for our dbt core project, which we're trying to automate the deployment by using GitHub Actions. The main `manifest.json` for the branch is stored in another repository.
We create a 'prod-run-artifacts' folder in our current project directory and copy this JSON file via GitHub Actions. Also we run a `dbt compile --target "dev" --profiles-dir '.github/profiles/'` command to create the manifest for the current version.

However, when we run the build command as below:
`dbt build --select "state:modified+" --target "dev" --defer --target-path prod-run-artifacts --profiles-dir '.github/profiles/'`

We get this error message:

> Unable to do partial parsing because saved manifest not found. Starting full parse.
> Runtime Error
> Got a state selector method, but no comparison manifest

We have also tried granting all kinds of access to the folders by running
`chmod 777 -R ./` 
in previous steps.
Also in local systems everything works fine.

Furthermore, running ls commands show:

```bash
ls ./prod-run-artifacts
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
manifest.json
```

```bash
ls ./target
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
manifest.json
partial_parse.msgpack
perf_info.json
semantic_manifest.json
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a flag the symbol where your manifest file
so just add at the end --state .

the full command should look like this

```
dbt build --select "state:modified+" --target "dev" --defer --target-path prod-run-artifacts --profiles-dir '.github/profiles/' --state .
```